# multiple controllers not running

Tags: angularjs, module, controller

Here is my code there are two different applications in which two different controllers but the later one is not running. Why is this happening both of these are two different modules?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>EggHead IO</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
<script>
var app=angular.module('ctrldemo', []);
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.name="yashdeep",
    $scope.age="21"

});
var papa=angular.module('anodemo', []);
papa.controller('anoFirstCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.name="yamini";
    $scope.age="22"
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="ctrldemo" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="greeting"/>
<div>
    {{greeting+"  "+name+"  "+age}}
</div>
</div>

<div ng-app="anodemo" ng-controller="anoFirstCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="greeeting">
<div>
    {{greeeting+"  "+name+"  "+age}}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have the example with single module having two controllers i wanna use two different module's controllers

Comment: If you want to run multiple angular apps, you will need to manually bootstrap the apps using angulars .bootstrap()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run multiple angular apps, you will need to manually bootstrap the apps using angulars [`.bootstrap()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/Ingular.bootstrap)

```
var app = angular.module('ctrldemo', []);
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "yashdeep",
    $scope.age = "21"

});

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('ctrldemo'), ['ctrldemo']);

var papa = angular.module('anodemo', []);
papa.controller('anoFirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "yamini";
    $scope.age = "22"
});

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('anodemo'), ['anodemo']);
```

You will also need to remove the ng-app from the HTML

```
<div id="ctrldemo" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="greeting" />
    <div>{{greeting+" "+name+" "+age}}</div>
</div>

<div id="anodemo" ng-controller="anoFirstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="greeeting">
    <div>{{greeeting+" "+name+" "+age}}</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/03qj5pwf/

Whether or not this is a good idea, I'm not too sure. I think it would be better to inject the modules into the app.

Comment: to be honest I didn't know you could have separate bootstraps in one page. Major disadvantage would be not being able to share services across the whole `app`. Interesting though

Comment: @vengicx Well, this is kinda outside of what the normal workings of angular, so DOM manipulation is fine here. But in general, try to avoid manipulating the DOM when using angular. If you really have no other choice, do it in a directive

Answer (score 1):

There can only be one `ng-app` in a page and angular can only be bootstrapped once.

In order to use separate modules you need to have one master module and inject other modules into it as dependencies

```
var app=angular.module('ctrldemo', ['anodemo']);

<html ng-app="ctrldemo">
```

Now you can use controllers, services, directives etc from either module

Comment: thanks man i was thinking about that but not having a clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do it at all the best way would be by using a directive. Which is what I did. It's called ngModule. Here is what your code would look like using it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.ng-modules.js"></script>
        <script>
          var moduleA = angular.module("MyModuleA", []);
          moduleA.controller("MyControllerA", function($scope) {
              $scope.name = "Bob A";
          });

          var moduleB = angular.module("MyModuleB", []);
          moduleB.controller("MyControllerB", function($scope) {
              $scope.name = "Steve B";
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-modules="MyModuleA, MyModuleB">
            <h1>Module A, B</h1>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerA">
                {{name}}
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerB">
                {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-module="MyModuleB">
            <h1>Just Module B</h1>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerB">
                {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```